# How to create a physical file with docpad?

Tags: node.js, docpad

There's too little information in the [docpad API page](http://docpad.org/docs/api#render-some-text-with-docpad) on creating a file.

This is what I've tried:

```
docpad.action("render", {
    text: content,
    filename: "random.html.md",
    path: "./src/documents/posts",
    attributes: {
        id: "some-random-id,
        title: "some-random-title",
        layout: "default"
    }
}, function(error, outContent, doc) {
    res.json({
        id: doc.get("id")
    });
});
```

It gives me the document instance, but there's no physical file being created.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I use to create virtual documents and write them to a file

```
outDirPath = docpad.config.outPath 

docAttr = {
    fullPath: null
    body: 'some content html to be rendered'
    outPath: outDirPath + '/index.html' # this where it will write the file
    extension: 'md'      
    extensions: ['html', 'md']
    relativePath: 'index.html'
    filename: 'index.html'
    write: true 
    render: true
    layout: 'somelayout'
}

# create the document
virtualDocument = docpad.createDocument(docAttr)
docpad.renderDocument virtualDocument, { templateData: this, someCustomData: extraData}, (err, content, file) ->
    # renderDocument complete callback
    file.write ()->
        # file.write complete callback
        return

    return
```